# sort only dictionary values that are lists within a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have this type of dict;

```
dict2 = {'value1': [ 2, ['get1', 3], ['post3', 4] ], 'value2' : [1, ['get1', 2], ['post2', 5] ], 'value3' : [7, ['get17', 6], ['post2', 2], ['post3', 3] ] }
```

I know how to order this based on the first value in the list (7, 2, 1). However once I've sorted it by the first value object, I want to sort the lists only based on the second value in each list.

For example like this;

```
'value3' : [7, ['get17', 6], ['post3', 3], ['post2', 2] ],
'value1': [ 2, ['post3', 4], ['get1', 3] ],
'value2' : [1,  ['post2', 5], ['get1', 2] ]
```

I've been looking into things like itemgetter but can't figure it out. Is this possible with python?

edit:

This is how I'm sorting the first value object, to print;

```
for key, value in sorted(dict2.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k), reverse=True):
    print key, value
```

To put into variable;

```
sort1 = sorted(dict2.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1, 1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider getting the items as a list or tuple and them sorting them with a function or lambda expression like so:

```
items = dict2.items()
items.sort(key=lambda x:x[1][0])
```

Comment: nice answer, could you please elaborate more how `lambda x,y: y[1][0] - x[1][0]` works?

Comment: `lambda` expressions are essentially temporary functions. `sort` can take a comparator and the function pointer I used was that lambda expression. A comparator should return `-1` if `x<y`, `+1` if `x>y`, and `0` if `x==y`. `y[1][0]` is the 1st element of the `tuple` (ie. the list) and the 0th element of the `list` (the first number). If you want to read more, see these pages: https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/ and https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how to sort based on the first value in the dict, let's focus on sorting the inner sequences.  The important step is to use slicing to trim-off the initial value so you can sort the remaining pairs:

```
>>> for key, seq in dict2.items():
        dict2[key] = seq[:1] + sorted(seq[1:], key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)


>>> pprint(dict2)
{'value1': [2, ['post3', 4], ['get1', 3]],
 'value2': [1, ['post2', 5], ['get1', 2]],
 'value3': [7, ['get17', 6], ['post3', 3], ['post2', 2]]}
```

Comment: That's awesome. But I realised the way i was initially sorting for the first value object conflicts with this. Please see my edit, in one instance I'm simply printing, and in the other it produces an output of tuples which I can't work with the above solution. Any ideas how I can implement the solution you've given but first the first value whilst maintaining the dictionaries format (so then I can sort by value lists)?